# converting an updatePanel to TELERIK

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

Using ASP.Net webforms I have a pop up containing 2 tabs, which display info on a feature, 'FEATURE PROPERTIES' and 'IMAGES'. Each time a new feature is clicked the pop up is updated with the new feature details.

I was making the call back to the server where updatePanel8 was being updated. Unfortuantelly I am trying to convert my website to telerik and I am having difficulties implenting this. I have read many Q's on telerik forms some suggest trying RadAjaxPanel others suggest tryiing RadAjaxManager, but either way I cant seem to get it working as I cant use an update panel inside a panel when I am using telerik.

```
**MY CODE:**
      <asp:Panel ID="ViewFeatureProperties" runat="server" BackColor="Snow" Width="300"
               HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
               <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel8" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
                   Style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; background-color: White;               
                  width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 5px; text-align: center; outline-style: none; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:hidden;">

                   <ContentTemplate>
                           <div id="DivHolding2Tabs" class="overflowcontent webkit-scrollbar webkit-scrollbar-track webkit-scrollbar-thumb" style="width:100%;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">
                               <ul id="tabList" style="width:100%"> 
                                   <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a> </li>
                                   <li><a href="#tabs-2" style="display:none;">Images</a> </li>
                               </ul>

                               <div id="tabs-1" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                                       <b><font color="FF6600">Feature Properties </font></b>
                                        <div id="divFeatureInfo" runat="server">
                                        </div>
                               </div>

                               <div id="tabs-2" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                                        <b><font color="FF6600">Images</font></b>
                                        <div id="ImagesRelatingToFeatureDIV" runat="server">  
                                       </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           <div class="buttonwrap">
                               <span id="Span5" class="ActionBtns">
                                   <asp:Button ID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn" runat="server" Style="display: none;
                                       visibility: hidden;" OnClick="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click" />
                               </span>
                           </div>

                   </ContentTemplate>
                   <Triggers>
                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn" EventName="Click" />
                   </Triggers>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
           </asp:Panel>

**CODE BEHIND**
protected void ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ReloadUploadedImagesForFeatureWorkflow();
}


private void ReloadUploadedImagesForFeatureWorkflow()
{
//generate the new details for the popup
UpdatePanel8.Update();
script.Append("OpenPropertiesPopUp();");

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel8,                                                        UpdatePanel8.GetType(),                                             "OpenPropertiesPopupCall()",
script.ToString(),
true);
}
```

---

---

Some exmaples I have tried are:

```
   <telerik:radajaxmanager id="ajaxManager1"  runat="server" UpdatePanelsRenderMode="Inline"><%-- defaultloadingpanelid="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">--%>
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ajaxManager1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:radajaxmanager>

         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <div id="Div1" class="overflowcontent webkit-scrollbar webkit-scrollbar-track webkit-scrollbar-thumb"
                             style="width: 100%; border-color: Black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;">

                         <asp:Button ID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn" runat="server" Text="Update the first Panel" OnClick="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click" />
                         <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label4"></asp:Label>


                             <ul id="Ul1" style="width: 100%">
                                 <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a> </li>
                                 <li><a href="#tabs-2" style="display: none;">Images</a> </li>
                             </ul>
                             <div id="tabs-1" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                                 <b><font color="FF6600">Feature Properties </font></b>
                                 <div id="divFeatureInfo" runat="server">
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div id="tabs-2" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                                 <b><font color="FF6600">Images</font></b>
                                 <div id="ImagesRelatingToFeatureDIV" runat="server">
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <br />
                         <br />
                         <div class="buttonwrap">
                             <span id="Span6" class="ActionBtns">
                                 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"
                                     OnClick="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click" />
                             </span>
                         </div>

         </asp:Panel>
         <br />

            <telerik:radajaxloadingpanel id="RadAjaxLoadingPanel2" runat="server" skin="Default"></telerik:radajaxloadingpanel>
```

**code behind**
UpdatePanel8.AjaxRequest;

```
        // UpdatePanel8.ResponseScripts.Add(String.Format("$find('{0}').ajaxRequest();", UpdatePanel8.ClientID));
```

Answer (score 0):

If calling the Update() server method is your requirement, I do not think you will be able to migrate to RadAjax. There is no server Update() method there, because the update panels are created dynamically.

If, however, you want to update Panel1 when ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn is clicked, you need an AJAX setup like this:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Black"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Panel1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Where I am assuming that the ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn button is still somewhere in the code. If it was replaced by a button with ID Button2, the AjaxControlID setting should use Button2 instead.